# Move Microsoft Access tables into SharePoint Lists inside a folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-access

I am trying use the SharePoint wizard in Developer Tools in Microsoft Access to move the tables into SharePoint Lists and link them. But the lists created using the wizard goes directly into the root directory of the SharePoint site, how do I make the lists created inside a folder in the SharePoint site?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO.

Per my test, even I specify a folder url in below textbox, it still creates the list under the root directory of the SharePoint site, not the new folder.

[image]

Comment: and can we create anyway SharePoint lists inside a folder? I mean using SharePoint itself.

Comment: I don't think we can. By default, there is no such option to select the folder when creating a list.